# Is there a way to wrap a class wish an elementwrapper inside another class with JaxB?

Tags: java, xml, class, nested, jaxb

I am trying to get an output from the xml which needs a wrapping of a class I already have. But I can't manage to wrap the elements.

I've already tried to `@XmlElementWrapper` the class, also already tried to nest in some ways, but none worked.

This is my Address class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="v41:address")
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String housenr;
    private String zip;
    private String city;

    public Address(String street, String housenr, String zip, String city) {
        setStreet(street);
        setHousenr(housenr);
        setZip(zip);
        setCity(city);
    }

    public Address(){

    }


    @XmlElement(name = "v41:street")
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "v41:houseNr")
    public String getHousenr() {
        return housenr;
    }

    public void setHousenr(String housenr) {
        this.housenr = housenr;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "v41:zip")
    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "v41:city")
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address{" +
                "street='" + street + '\'' +
                ", housenr=" + housenr +
                ", zip=" + zip +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And this is my Request class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="v41:request")
public class WSGRequest {
    private String ispId;
    private String returnSpeekAtNok;
    private String basisContrEleId;
    private String contrEleId;
    private String bbType;
    private String dnType;
    private String qualifExtRef;
    private String correlationId;
    private String correlationValue;





public WSGRequest(String ispId, String returnSpeekAtNok, String basisContrEleId, String contrEleId, String bbType, String dnType, String qualifExtRef, String correlationId) {
        setIspId(ispId);
        setReturnSpeekAtNok(returnSpeekAtNok);
        setBasisContrEleId(basisContrEleId);
        setContrEleId(contrEleId);
        setBbType(bbType);
        setDnType(dnType);
        setQualifExtRef(qualifExtRef);
        setCorrelationid(correlationId);

    }

    public WSGRequest() {

    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getCorrelationid() {
        return correlationId;
    }

    public void setCorrelationid(String correlationid) {
        this.correlationId = correlationid;
    }

    public String getCorrelationValue() {
        return correlationValue;
    }

    public void setCorrelationValue(String correlationValue) {
        this.correlationValue = correlationValue;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "v41:ispId")
    public String getIspId() {
        return ispId;
    }

    public void setIspId(String ispId) {
        this.ispId = ispId;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "v41:returnSpeedAtNok")
    public String getReturnSpeekAtNok() {
        return returnSpeekAtNok;
    }

    public void setReturnSpeekAtNok(String returnSpeekAtNok) {
        this.returnSpeekAtNok = returnSpeekAtNok;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "v41:basisContrEleId")
    public String getBasisContrEleId() {
        return basisContrEleId;
    }

    public void setBasisContrEleId(String basisContrEleId) {
        this.basisContrEleId = basisContrEleId;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "v41:contrEleId")
    public String getContrEleId() {
        return contrEleId;
    }

    public void setContrEleId(String contrEleId) {
        this.contrEleId = contrEleId;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "v41:bbType")
    public String getBbType() {
        return bbType;
    }

    public void setBbType(String bbType) {
        this.bbType = bbType;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "v41:dnType")
    public String getDnType() {
        return dnType;
    }

    public void setDnType(String dnType) {
        this.dnType = dnType;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "v41:qualifExtRef")
    public String getQualifExtRef() {
        return qualifExtRef;
    }

    public void setQualifExtRef(String qualifExtRef) {
        this.qualifExtRef = qualifExtRef;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "WSGRequest{" +
                "ispId='" + ispId + '\'' +
                ", returnSpeekAtNok='" + returnSpeekAtNok + '\'' +
                ", basisContrEleId='" + basisContrEleId + '\'' +
                ", contrEleId='" + contrEleId + '\'' +
                ", bbType='" + bbType + '\'' +
                ", dnType='" + dnType + '\'' +
                ", qualifExtRef='" + qualifExtRef + '\'' +
                ", correlationId='" + correlationId + '\'' +
                ", correlationValue='" + correlationValue + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    /***** STATIC CLASS ADDRESS ******/
    /*
    public static class Address {
        private String street;
        private String housenr;
        private String zip;
        private String city;

        public Address(String street, String housenr, String zip, String city) {
            setStreet(street);
            setHousenr(housenr);
            setZip(zip);
            setCity(city);
        }

        public Address(){

        }


        @XmlElement(name = "v41:street")
        public String getStreet() {
            return street;
        }

        public void setStreet(String street) {
            this.street = street;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "v41:houseNr")
        public String getHousenr() {
            return housenr;
        }

        public void setHousenr(String housenr) {
            this.housenr = housenr;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "v41:zip")
        public String getZip() {
            return zip;
        }

        public void setZip(String zip) {
            this.zip = zip;
        }

        @XmlElement(name = "v41:city")
        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Address{" +
                    "street='" + street + '\'' +
                    ", housenr=" + housenr +
                    ", zip=" + zip +
                    ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }

    /*** FINE STATIC CLASS ADDRESS *****/

}
```

I need to get this output:

```
<v41:srvQualifByAddress>
             <v41:request correlationId="test">
                    <v41:ispId>x</v41:ispId>
                             <v41:returnSpeedAtNok>x</v41:returnSpeedAtNok>
                   <v41:basisContrEleId>x</v41:basisContrEleId>
                <v41:contrEleId>x</v41:contrEleId>
                <v41:bbType>x</v41:bbType>
                <v41:dnType>x</v41:dnType>
                <v41:qualifExtRef>x</v41:qualifExtRef>
                <v41:address>
                                   <v41:street>x</v41:street>
                                   <v41:houseNr>x</v41:houseNr>
                                   <v41:zip>x</v41:zip>
                                   <v41:city>x</v41:city>
                </v41:address>
             </v41:request>
          </v41:srvQualifByAddress>
```

Basically, the address wrapper should contain the elements of my address class...

My method to Marshal is the following:

```
public static String requestJaxObjectToXML(WSGRequest request){
        try{
            //CREATE JAXB Context
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(WSGRequest.class);

            //Create Marshaller
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            /*Required Formatting?*/
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);

            //Print XML String to Console
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            //Write XML to Stringwriter
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(request, sw);

            String xmlContent = sw.toString();

            return xmlContent;
        }
        catch(JAXBException e){
            //return e.getCause().toString();
            return "ERROR!";


        }
    }
```

and this is part of my code in the "main" section

```
 WSGRequest request = new WSGRequest("100032", "true", "110", "100", "2", "1", "#myTicId", "test");
        String completeRequest = requestJaxObjectToXML(request);
```

What I would like to have, is a String that contains the XML call like I posted above, maybe having an Address object inside the constructor.

Comment: There is currently no `Adress` fields in your `WSGRequest` class, what have you tried exactly ?

Comment: There are, but they are like comments, because otherwise the code would give me an error. I have tried to XmlElementWrapper the class, which doesn't work. I've also tried to make make Address as an XmlElement inside WSGRequest (getter of Address class). Now to avoid the problem I was about to just put the fields of Address inside WSGRequest, but not as a class, just as fields. But that's not the way I want it to work, that would be too much hardcode and static.

Comment: I've resolved the problem. I just inserted the XML generated from the address class inside the request by using index of and substrings. :)